# modx: how can I add different manager languages for different users?

Tags: php, modx

Is there an easy way to have the language of the modx backend interface (manager) on a per user basis? e.g. admin sees the backend in english, user 1 sees it in french, user2 in italian. 
the only thing I could find so far was a global setting in System -> System Settings

I'm running modX 2.0.7.

EDIT:
I've found a way of doing it in later versions of modx by adding a custom user setting that overwrites manager_language. but 2.0.7 doesn't allow  you to add custom settings of type modx-combo-language.
updating my modx version might be a bit tricky as quite a few developers have worked on it over the last 2 years and it might break something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already realised, you can override `manager_language` on a per-user basis setting by adding it to that user's Settings tab.

`modx-combo-language` might not be available in 2.0.7 but you can still add the setting as a textfield, then enter the ISO code of the language you want (eg. en, it, fr, es).

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and as far as I can see, it's not possible.

Because the language is set in the system-settings this is (like you said) global. You could suggest this as a future feature because it would not work at this time without doing some heavy editing in the core-files.

Comment: there's a way of doing it in later versions of modx by adding a custom user setting that overwrites manager_language. but 2.0.7 doesn't allow  you to add custom settings of type modx-combo-language.